# Does the rejection of moral relativism intellectually necessitate moral axioms that are logically indefensible?

Tags: ethics, relativism

Personally, I believe it's fair to assume nature/reality has no purpose. Quite often, people that, like myself, have some interest in natural sciences, agree that there are good reasons to believe nature/reality has no purpose.

However, when asked whether they believe morals are therefor relative, quite often they seem to disagree. I've never really asked them how they want to defend that position though.

But now, I just wanted to ask people who might recognize them selfs in said position (rejecting moral relativism while at the same time assuming no purpose in nature). How does one intellectually defend such a position?

To be clear; I'm not talking about what is an emotionally desirable position to take, but rather the intellectually honest position to concede. I can totally understand that if one intellectually comes to the conclusion that morals are indeed relative, there may still be an emotional need to reject moral relativism and for instance prefer a utilitarian approach to ethics.

However, is there an intellectually honest approach to construct moral axioms that are still ultimately logically defensible?

I, for instance, haven't come up with any logically convincing manner to extrapolate judgment values (good, bad, nice, beautiful, ugly, etc.) from the logical values true or false.

Are people that reject the idea that morals are relative, when conceding the large probability that nature/reality has no purpose, fooling them selfs intellectually?

Comment: There are hundreds, perhaps thousands, of introductory ethics textbooks that give an overview of numerous competing attempts to ground ethics, pretty much all of which could be considered "intellectually honest".  I suggest you take a look at a few; perhaps that can be a first step.

Comment: @Michael Dorfman: Would it be fair to say though, that all these attempts to ground ethics (in logic) have failed thus far? I mean, after centuries of moral philosophy, it seems we still haven't found the "General Theory of Ethics" (compared to numerous demonstrable theories in physics), so to speak. At least, I would think I would have heard about it already then, through numerous news outlets, just like I became aware of the General Theory of Relativity in physics, for example. Not saying that this is a decisive indicator, but isn't that a plausible indicator that it probably *is* undo-able?

Comment: I wouldn't say so, no.  Most philosophical questions are still open questions-- that's why we're still doing philosophy.  And I don't think that analogies to physics are generally useful-- there are significant differences between the two domains.  If ethics actually interests you, there are a lot of resources out there.  If your interest is not serious enough to warrant further investigation on your part, what are we doing here?

Comment: @Michael Dorfman: I am interested in arguments against my proposition that objective morals cannot emerge from purposelessness. Do some of the philosophical bodies of work you are referring to posit that nature has no intrinsic purpose? If so; do you know of any of them that, in your opinion, make a compelling case that objective morality can nonetheless still emerge from that kind of nature? I'd love to read those, since that is what my question boils down to.
And "significant differences between the two domains"? What significant differences are there in applying logic vs. applying logic?

Comment: Before we could even begin to answer your question, we'd need to pin down mutually acceptable definitions of "purpose"/"purposelessness", and "objectivity", to begin with.  But the short answer is, yes, there exist ethical systems that do not rely on the notion of a purpose-directed natural world.  But as I said, I suggest you start with a basic textbook on ethics, to get an overview of the field.

Comment: As for the differences between philosophy and physics, neither of those domains reduce to "applying logic".  In the case of physics, we are speaking about controlled observation and testable hypotheses, and in the case of philosophy, we generally have neither; put another way, if a problem can be solved by the traditional scientific method, it's probably not a philosophical problem.  This distinction goes back to Aristotle, at least.

Comment: "[...] there exist ethical systems that do not rely on the notion of a purpose-directed natural world." I'm sure there are. However, do those systems claim to have objective moral axioms? And if so, what are they? BTW: It seems you already have an idea of what I mean by purpose. So I'll take your definition of it, to avoid ending up in endless semantic games. And I'll just assume you have a reasonable idea of what I mean by objective then also. But in case you are unsure, I propose the second sentence of this Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objectivity_(philosophy)

Comment: Is philosophy ultimately not about applying logical reasoning to try to come up with plausible hypotheses about reality? And is the scientific method also not the result of logical reasoning done in the field of the philosophy of science? I mean, you are right of course; there is a distinction between the domains, but ultimately their results will be (in)validated by the scrutiny of logic.

Comment: Logic is rarely the critical factor in philosophical investigations; it is necessary, but far from sufficient.  As for your larger question-- utilitarianism is considered an objective ethical system (by the very Wikipedia article you quote, no less), and certainly does not require an external purpose to the natural world.

Comment: "Logic is rarely the critical factor in philosophical investigations" I may have put too much emphasis on logic indeed. Investigation can be as irrational and illogical as one wishes, as far as I'm concerned. But to determine whether there's any (probable) truth value in the conclusions of the investigations, surely one must ultimately apply logic, no?
"utilitarianism is considered an objective ethical system" as long as one bases this consideration on the subjective moral axiom that the human species must survive, I presume? Otherwise, I can't fathom how one can call this objective.

Comment: The issue you are raising is one of definition, and as you've noticed, definition plays a much larger role in philosophy than logic does.  The Wikipedia page you referenced (on Objectivity in philosophy) indeed lists utilitarianism as an objective philosophy; that's why I've recommended that you check out an Ethics textbook, to gain familiarity with the definitions in common usage. Once the definitions are clear, you'll find that the logical issues are often trivial-- the hard part is agreeing on the definitions (and the implications thereof).

Comment: I feel like this question should be reformulated or bifurcated. I misunderstood it the first time when I wrote my answer. There seem to be 2 distinct questions being asked and some answers regard one of the questions, while others refer to the other question. They are similar, but not the same.

- Is there an intellectually honest approach to construct moral axioms that are still ultimately logically defensible?
- Are people that reject the idea that morals are relative, when conceding the large probability that nature/reality has no purpose, fooling them selfs intellectually?

Answer (score 4):

Axioms by definition cannot be logically defended: logic is the process of applying reasoning to a set of postulates.  So, in mathematics, Euclid took as axiomatic that parallel lines never meet: that cannot be mathematically proved or disproved, but without it geometry cannot get off the ground. Other geometers took as axiomatic that parallel lines meet (e.g exactly twice, as on the surface of a sphere), and came up with workable, non-Euclidean geometries.

Ethics is similar: you take what you consider to be ethical imperatives, and deduce what actions are moral.  Ethical imperatives include "act for the greatest good of the greatest number", "act in accordance with the wishes of the Creator [defined in some way]" , and "act so as to ensure the survival and growth of the human species". All of these are valid bases for systems of morality (you may even recognize them), but intellectual honesty only comes into it when you claim to believe in one imperative, but dislike or refuse to accept that *this action* is the logical consequence.

And yes, in a sense this is entirely subjective; but it is also subjective that you choose to speak English (not Latin or your own invented language), and say that 2+2=4, not 17.

Answer (score 1):

The distinction between relativism and objectivism is, pragmatically, not particularly important when there is only one thing that one needs to relate to.  Thus, aside from various thought experiments, the distinction collapses when talking about e.g. innate morality in humans or evolutionary pressures on social organisms (two very powerful sources of justification for morality).

You don't have to start from scratch when using logic; you've got the entire world of observations to work with.  For example:

- Creatures that try to survive are better at surviving than those who don't.
- We are descended from an amazingly long line of survivors.
- Therefore, we have been shaped to try to survive.
- Therefore, if you try to kill someone, it is likely to provoke a very negative reaction from them.
- As social primates, we rely upon positive reactions from our social group.
- Value judgments help us maintain mutually positive reactions
- Since trying to kill someone is so negative, it is entirely sensible to judge that as bad

Comment: I understand your line of reasoning, but I believe this is exactly what I refer to with logically indefensible moral axioms. Because I believe this line of reasoning is based on the moral axiom that the human species must somehow survive. But when one concedes (for arguments sake) that reality has no purpose, then reality couldn't care less whether the human species (or any other species for that matter) survives. Only moral agents (like our selfs) care about it. And that, in itself, make these types of moral axioms subjective, no?

Comment: @Rex - This is exactly what I started to write but then I realized that technically it was outside the scope of his question. But I do agree with your thinking. :)

Comment: @fireeyedboy - Non-nihilism is logically indefensible, depending on what you mean by "logically indefensible".  Asking for too much and then failing to get it is a bad way to increase one's knowledge of the world.

Comment: @Rex Kerr: I think I got your first paragraph perfectly fine Rex, but I can see why you feel I didn't; I just was a bit too eager to dish out my "nihilistic" argument. ;-) As long as opponents of moral-relativism at least subscribe to what you said, I don't think I would blame them of being "intellectually dishonest".

Comment: @Rex Kerr: Now that I reread your comment again I'm starting to doubt whether I even interpreted your comment correctly. I interpreted it as you critiquing me for "asking too much" and having not gotten your answer. But on rereading it, I'm not so sure anymore. Was I correct, or was the last sentence referring to your statement that "Non-nihilism is logically indefensible"? In that case, it's a bit cryptic for me. Can you expand?

Comment: @fireeyedboy - I was critiquing both you and nihilists.  The surest way to nihilism is to demand more from your epistemology than the world can provide.  Anyway, if you read carefully, I don't assume that our species has to survive; rather, I make the educated guess that _we evolved value judgments in order to help us survive_, and that if we abstract away one level from actually _feeling_ that something is bad, we can logically assess that, yes, this is "bad" (by the metric that selected for the feeling). If you reject that style of reasoning, I think you'll find yourself halfway to nihilism.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes. It doesn't make sense to reject both moral objectivism and moral relativism at the same time. It would be like believing in something and not believing in something simultaneously.